# Use of DLM and DSD at same time in SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and learning it at the moment.
I have read that we can use both DSD and DLM options to the infile statement.

But however i get an error when executing the below with data having multiple delimiters.

**Code:**

```
data test;
infile cards dlm='@' dsd;
input pid visit $ dose;
cards;
101,vis1"0.05
102,vis2,0.1
```

**Error:**

```
NOTE: Invalid data for pid in line 254 1-8.
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8---
255        102,vis2,10mg
NOTE: Invalid data errors for file CARDS occurred outside the printed range.
NOTE: Increase available buffer lines with the INFILE n= option.
pid=. vist=05mg drug=102,vis2 _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
NOTE: The data set WORK.MH1 has 1 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

256  ;
```

Could you please help me in understanding this to build my knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your DLM is '@' (meaning you say the field delimiter is @ character) but your data shows ',' as the delimiter (comma).

As such, your error is that SAS is trying to read all of hta ("102,vis2,10mg") into one numeric field (pid).   You either need to change to `dlm=','` or have different data.

Comment: Joe, i have tried the above as i read that we can use dlm and dsd at same time.I am wondering if i use `DSD` why is  the comma separation not delimited.

Comment: `DSD` has nothing to do with comma separated.  `DSD` tells SAS to do a few things, primary of which is to treat a delimiter value that appears in matched quotation marks as not a delimiter.  So `102,"visit, nurse disagrees",10mg` for example would need DSD to read in correctly because of the comma in the second field.  But `DSD` works just as well with any delimiter - `102@"jamessmith@wustl.edu"@10mg` would work fine with `dlm='@' DSD` options.